# grab value from multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am presented with an object with the following information

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [campaigns_id] => 100 [views] => 28 )
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [campaigns_id] => 99 [views] => 346 )
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [campaigns_id] => 98 [views] => 73 )
        [3] => stdClass Object ( [campaigns_id] => 97 [views] => 204 )
        [4] => stdClass Object ( [campaigns_id] => 96 [views] => 10 )
        [5] => stdClass Object ( [campaigns_id] => 57 [views] => 12 )
      )
```

Basically, it has two values for each row -- an ID and a count of views.

If I had a "campaign ID" of "100" how would I be able to successfully grab the number "28" from this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
//$arr is the array, loop through it
foreach ($arr as $v) {
 if( $v->campaigns_id === 100 ) //Similarly you can get any other value for 'views'
  echo $v->views;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your array

```
$yourval = 0;;

foreach( $yourarray as $id => $val ){

if( $val->campaigns_id === 100 ){
  $yourval = $val->views;
}

}

echo $yourval;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this inline or as a function, I think it may be easier for you to see as a function, so here it is.

```
$view = get_view($the_array);

function get_view(& $my_array) {

  foreach($my_array as $object) {

    if($object->campaigns_id == 100) return $object->views;

  }

  return false;

}
```